# angular ngressource issue TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, angularjs-service

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to to create a service to register and login users using a spring rest controller, below is the Angular code to retrive Json data

```
.factory('accountService', function($resource) {
var service = {};
service.register = function(account, success, failure) {
    var Account = $resource("/mywebapp/rest/account");
    Account.save({}, account, success, failure);
};
service.userExists = function(account, success, failure) {
    var Account = $resource("/mywebapp/rest/account");
    var data = account.get({email:'email'}, function() {
        var accounts = data.accounts;
        if(accounts.length !== 0) {
            success(accounts[0]);
        } else {
            failure();
        }
    },
    failure);
};
return service;
```

})

the problem is that i'm getting two type of error message in chrome and FireFox when trying to connect (service.userExists):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at Object.service.userExists (http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/js/account.js:42:27)
at h.$scope.login (http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/js/account.js:56:24)
at http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:178:68
at f (http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:195:177)
at h.$eval (http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:113:32)
at h.$apply (http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:113:310)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:195:229)
at http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:31:225
at r (http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:7:290)
at HTMLFormElement.c (http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:31:207)
```

and in firefox:
`"Error: account is undefined
service.userExists@http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/js/account.js:42:13
$scope.login@http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/js/account.js:56:1
gb.prototype.functionCall/<@http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:178:66
jc[c]</<.compile/</</f@http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:195:177
Yd/this.$get</h.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:113:28
Yd/this.$get</h.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:113:305
jc[c]</<.compile/</<@http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:195:227
ne/c/<@http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:31:223
r@http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:7:288
ne/c@http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/resources/lib/angular/angular.js:31:207`

i'm also getting this error when trying to register a new account:

```
 [HTTP/1.1 415 Type de Support Non Supporté 98ms]
```

Would you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

ng-resource seems to never receive the `account` parameter which means the get request is not returning the account. Check the network tools to see what the userExists request is returning from the server.

The message your are receiving for the `register` could be a hint, I would say it means the API doesn't support your type of client, maybe you're using an old browser or a the server API is very old.

Comment: yep, for the first error it was that, I'm receiving now the Json querry from the server and I have to compare the login and password on both sides (client and server) however for the register function, I didn't understand your message, in fact I'm using last version of Firefox and Chrome as browser and Tomcat 7 as web server and Spring 4 on the server side.